# reactive-banana-wx `sink` does not generate an event enabling post-sink processing

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, frp, reactive-banana

I am currently redesigning a piece of legacy wxHaskell using the reactive-banana and reactive-banana-wx packages. However, in order to avoid dynamic network construction (where I ran into a thread block on an MVar), I now mimic this by preconstructing a fixed set of wxHaskell widgets of which I set visibility as necessary. Visibility is set by the `sink` function taking a `Behavior`. However, wxHaskell requires that after all these widgets have been appropriately modified via `sink`, a subsequent change of the layout of the panel holding these widgets is required. That would mean that `sink`-ing actually should be part of a network, so it is an event which can be triggered and waited upon for a layout change. As it currently is, a `sink` takes you 'out' of the event network, it is not possible to trigger an event after the `sink` action is completed. I did try to adapt `sink` to something like this:

```
sink' :: Frameworks t =>
    w -> [Prop' t w] -> Moment t (Event t ())
sink' widget props = do
    es <- mapM sink1 props
    return $ unions es
  where
    sink1 (attr :== b) = do
        x <- initial b
        liftIOLater $ set widget [attr := x]
        e <- changes b
        return $ (\x -> unsafePerformIO $ set widget [attr := x]) <$> e
```

However, the `unsafePerformIO` did not get executed. How can the desired behavior be achieved, i.e. allow a (wxHaskell) IO to be waited on by means of an `Event`?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it appears that you want to ensure that the IO actions in `reactimate` are executed in a certain order? Namely, you want to make sure that the layout is set *after* the widget properties have been set.

There are several methods to specify order:

1. Use `union`, `unionWith` and/or `collect` to determine the order of simultaneous events.
2. Use the fact that `reactimate` are executed in the order they appear in the `Moment` monad. (Though strictly speaking, this is no longer true when you use the `observeE` combinator from dynamic event switching.)

In your particular case, these ideas can be applied as follows.

For 1, you can make an event that contains an IO action and combine it with the layout later

```
sink' :: Frameworks t =>
    w -> [Prop' t w] -> Moment t (Event t (IO ()))
sink' widget props = do
    es <- mapM sink1 props
    return $ foldr1 (unionWith (>>)) es
  where
    sink1 (attr :== b) = do
        x <- initial b
        liftIOLater $ set widget [attr := x]
        e <- changes b
        return $ (\x -> set widget [attr := x]) <$> e
```

For 2, you can simply use the ordinary `sink` functions and just make sure that the layout is set last.

```
do
    sink widget1 [ visible :== bBool ]
    sink window1 [ layout  :== bLayout ]
```

The ordering of the `sink` functions in the monad guarantees that the layout is set last.

---

Also note that since reactive-banana 0.7, you can use dynamic event switching to model a variable set of widgets. See the [BarTab.hs example](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Reactive-banana/Examples#bartab) for a demonstration. This example also sets the layout.

You indicated that you run into an MVar block when you use dynamic networks. This is probably because you create widgets in a way that triggers another event in the network. Unfortunately, this is semantically unsound — it corresponds to values depending on future versions of themselves — and the program responds by plunging into rock bottom.

Comment: Thanks! About the `BarTab.hs` example, I did copy its behavior. BarTab dynamically computes an increment of a list of widgets, this increment is independent of the previous list. The increment I tried to construct however does depend on the previous list. I guess it went wrong there, and will probably retry it later on, maybe giving rise to another post.

Comment: Ok, let me know if anything else pops up.